Does the ellipsoid method imply the existence of a polynomial size minimum unsatisfiable subset for each unsatisfiable LP?
Consider an LP with an exponential number of constraints. We assume you can upper- and lower-bound the the size of the solution space if it is non-empty. The ellipsoid method implies that in a polynomial number of steps (in the dimension and size of the upper/lower bound) it can be determined whether a solution exists by continuously shrinking the size of an ellipsoid that contains the solution space until either a solution is found or the size of the ellipsoid is smaller than the lower bound.
In each step, a violating constraint is found to shrink the search space. Since the number of violating constraints is polynomial this should imply that there is a polynomial size subset of unsatisfiable constraints, if I am not mistaken.
While this is not relevant for LPs, where the exponential number of constraints blows up the size of the encoding, there are problems that can be encoded as LPs with an exponential number of constraints for which this result may be useful.
I am not sure whether I made a mistake, since I was not able to find this result in any of the papers/book chapters on the ellipsoid method I looked at.
